# Java How to convert string to UTF-16BE from request.getParameter() function?

Tags: java, utf-16

I am now using the following code but it doesn't performs well. Only few words can be convert.

```
public String convert(String big5) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] tmp = big5.getBytes( "UTF-16BE");
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toHexString(((int)tmp[i]));
    }

    return result.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what you are tyring to do. Why convert the bytes and chars back and forth so many times?

Comment: the input is from a webpage which is big5 and output wish to be UTF-16BE

Comment: i don't know how exactly how it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
result += Integer.toHexString(((int)(tmp[i] & 0xFF)));
```

To treat a byte value as unsigned, you need to do a bitwise & with 0xFF.

Hope this helps.